# Perguntas sobre PowerShell é dentro ou fora do escopo do site?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, escopo-do-site

Vi esta pergunta [Renomear arquivos em lote usando Windows Power Shell](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96545/3635), votei por fechar, não entendo muito de PowerShell, mas acreditava ser algo semelhante ao Terminal do Linux.

Então notei que duas pessoas votaram por deixar aberta, fiquei na duvida, só por abordar o uso de `ForEach` e *variáveis* isto leva a ser uma questão valida por site?

Ou realmente [powershell](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) é muito mais que um "terminal windows"?

Eu ia até remover meu voto de fechamento, mas preferi manter, pois sempre mantenho o pensamento se foi fechado por engano pode ser reaberto sem crise.

Comment: Está dentro do escopo sim! é uma linguagem. Escopo de variável ? xD

Comment: Escopo de variável !  :P olha a confusão que causo, calma ae vou editar kk

Comment: É uma pena que não tenham mais perguntas de powershell.

Comment: @rray vai ver que é porque alguns podem pensar algo semelhante ao que pensei. Por enquanto retirei o voto de fechamento, mas comentei com um link pra este debate lá na pergunta. Obrigado por enquanto!

Comment: Eu não entendi o segundo paragrafo ,"só por abortar o uso de ForEach e variáveis isto leva a ser uma questão valida por site". Ou talvez a galera prefira bat ainda haha

Comment: @rray to com sono, kk foi erro de digitação, era abordar, melhor ir descansar. -- Concordo, a galera deve preferir o bat.

Comment: Tranquilo, powershell normalmente é usado para linha de comando mesmo mas alguns malucos importam libs(assemblies) do .net e conseguem criar aplicativos com interface grafica. Você pode resolver o problema com uma linha ou adotar uma abordagem mais organizada como nas linguaguens tradicionais.

Comment: GuilhermeNascimento fiquei com o pé atrás na hora de trazer o tema, porém vi que a tag powershell já foi usada em 13 perguntas então vi que havia um precedente fora que se assemelha com o bash (na minha cabeça)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perguntas relacionadas a powershell estão dentro do escopo do site desde que tenham a estrutura mínima para serem respondidas ou seja tenham detalhes suficientes para reproduzir o defeito ou uma boa explicação do objetivo daquele código.

Powershell normalmente é usado para automatizar algumas tarefas via linha de comando mas também é possível criar 'aplicativos' com interface gráfica importando alguns assemblies do .net.

O que faz uma pergunta dentro ou fora do escopo está mais ligado ao contexto e o objetivo descrito do que da própria tecnologia, mesmo perguntas sobre C, java e outra linguagens são fechadas por pedirem algo fora do escopo ou pela falta de objetividade/clareza.

Answer (score 7):

Não é bom confundir "programação" com "tem pelo menos uma palavra reservada na pergunta ou resposta"!

Nosso site é sobre programação e para programadores. E nossa [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) é bem clara a respeito de perguntas sobre "ferramentas comuns entre programadores".

Uma pergunta sobre PowerShell (ou qualquer outro shell) muito provavelmente tem tudo a ver com nosso site e nossa comunidade... Talvez se fosse "Por que a fonte do PowerShell é tão horrorosa" ela pudesse estar fora do escopo do nosso site, mas como realizar uma tarefa de automação? Ainda mais uma não trivial, que pode facilmente ser scriptada? Não vejo problema algum...

Comment: Entendo, então isto valeria pra terminais like-unix? Já que suportam `for` e `if`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento De novo, a questão não é quantas palavras reservadas podem ser usadas no shell, mas sim o fato de que o shell é uma ferramenta extremamente comum em programação, e que usá-lo de maneira eficiente é muito benéfico ao dia a dia de programadores. É equivalente à uma pergunta sobre Eclipse, ou NetBeans, etc. Podem existir casos que fugirão do alcance do site, mas isso não pode ser decidido com base apenas no tema.

Comment: Entendo seu argumento, apenas quis dizer que os terminais like-unix suportam podem ser talvez usados de maneira semelhante e neste caso teremos que ver caso a caso cada pergunta. Desculpe se não me fiz entender de inicio.